# Android XML Parsing with RSS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have My Rss File Items :

```
<item >
<title>Prasad</title>
<link>http://www.tele.com/rssHostDescr.php?hostId=15</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.tele.com/rssHostDescr.php?hostId=14</guid>
<pubDate>2013-04-10</pubDate>
<description>Prasad</description>
<media:thumbnail width='66' height='49' url='http://www.tele.com/hos/Panthi-image.jpg'></media:thumbnail>
</item>
<item>
........................
</item>

etc.....................
```

I'm trying to parse the above file,I'm able to get all the information(title,link,date)but my requirement is to get   url attribute value. How do I get the URL value from media:thumbnail tag? Could any one help?

Here's my code:

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://www.tele.com/RSSFeed/toriHos.php";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TITLE=  "title";

    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    static final String KEY_PUBDATE = "pubDate";
    static final String KEY_MEDIA = "media:thumbnail";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        NodeList n=doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_MEDIA);

        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
            map.put(KEY_PUBDATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PUBDATE));
            map.put(KEY_MEDIA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_MEDIA));//Here I'm not getting any value

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:map.put(KEY_MEDIA, parser.getValue(e, KEY_MEDIA));//Here I'm not getting any value**

Answer (score 1):

```
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
String urlStr = e.getAttribute("url");
```

Hope this will help you.