# Android XML Parsing using SAXParser

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, saxparser

I have My RSS File Items :

```
<item >
<title>Prasad</title>
<link>http://www.tele.com/rssHostDescr.php?hostId=15</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.tele.com/rssHostDescr.php?hostId=14</guid>
<pubDate>2013-04-10</pubDate>
<description>Prasad</description>
<media:thumbnail width='66' height='49' url='http://www.tele.com/hos/Panthi-image.jpg'></media:thumbnail>
</item>
<item>
........................
</item>

etc.....................
```

I'm trying to parse the above file,I'm able to get all the information(title,link,date)but my requirement is to get   url attribute value,How to get the URL value from media:thumbnail tag? Could any one help?

here my code:

```
public class HostsRssHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private List<HostsProfile> messages;
    private HostsProfile currentMessage;
    private StringBuilder builder;

    public List<HostsProfile> getMessages(){
        return messages;
    }
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        builder.append(ch, start, length);
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, name);
        if (this.currentMessage != null){
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tilte")){
                currentMessage.setTitle(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                currentMessage.setLink(builder.toString());
            }
                else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")){
                    currentMessage.setMediathumbnail(builder.toString());
                }
             else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                currentMessage.setDate(builder.toString());
            }


            else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                messages.add(currentMessage);
            }
            builder.setLength(0);   
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.startDocument();
        messages = new ArrayList<HostsProfile>();
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
            this.currentMessage = new HostsProfile();
        }
    }   
}
```

Note:

```
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")){
                    currentMessage.setMediathumbnail(builder.toString());// During My Program Execution, Here I'm not able to get any value
                }
```

Comment: use DOM parser same problem with me..i resolved with this!!!

Comment: Could you provide me the Source Code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12108840/1339473

Comment: @altaf I have used Dom Parser,not getting the value ,Please check this what went wrong here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962749/andriod-xml-parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the value from the attribute so it has to be in `startElement`:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
        this.currentMessage = new HostsProfile();
    }
    //Validate that localName has the value you want. In theory localName shouldn't have the prefix
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("thumbnail")) { 
      currentMessage.setMediaThumbnail(attributes.getValue("url"));
    }
}
```